# Looking for a Javascript engine, outside of the Webkit

Tags: javascript, iphone, cocoa-touch

Do pardon the simplicity of the question: mother Google seems not to the have the answer to this one ...

So Java has Rhino, a Javascript engine written in Java. Is there a similarly shaped library out there for processing JavaScript in a Cocoa-touch environment? To be specific - this means *not* using the UIWebView.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the iOS guidelines forbid using any JavaScript engine outside of webkit, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I would be really grateful if you could post an update of your findings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [this (old) page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SpiderMonkey), there’s mention of a bridge between [SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) (Mozilla’s C-based Javascript engine) and Objective-C.  Maybe that’s something to explore?

Besides, isn’t JavascriptCore the iPhone’s javascript engine?

Lastly, perhaps this is what you’re looking for?
http://parmanoir.com/Taming_JavascriptCore_within_and_without_WebView

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [Google V8 JavaScript Engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) could be built for iOS?  It seems to build on Linux/ARM so iOS (Darwin/ARM), theoretically, couldn't be too far off =)

Answer (score 0):

Webkit is a web browser engine.  So, techincally any JavaScript interpreter/compiler is "outside of the Webkit".

[V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) is used in [Google Chrome](http://google.com/chrome) (which uses Webkit) and [Node.js](http://nodejs.org), [SquirrelFish Extreme](http://www.webkit.org/blog/214/introducing-squirrelfish-extreme/) is used in [Safari](http://apple.com/safari) (which uses Webkit), [SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) for [Mozilla Firefox](http://getfirefox.com), and [Chakra](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/18/the-new-javascript-engine-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx) for [IE9](http://www.beautyoftheweb.com/).  Take your pick.

Comment: Actually, SpiderMonkey is Firefox’s javascript engine.  JägerMonkey is just the JIT method that’s applied to SpiderMonkey.  Also, I don’t think Node.js uses Webkit, seeing as it’s server-side software.

Comment: yeah, had the webkit next to Chrome, you're right - node is just using V8 in C++ (fixed)

Comment: also, you're right about SpiderMonkey being the engine - I just know many people typically call SpiderMonkey + TraceMonkey = JaegerMonkey, but you're right, it's just JIT (and TraceMonkey is using trace trees), corrected again